# How to get a literal type from a function argument for a computed property name?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

please consider the following code:

```js
const fn = (name: string) => {
  return { [name]: "some txt" };
};

const res = fn("books"); // books or any other string
```

TS recognizes `res` as the following type:

```js
const res: {
  [x: string]: string;
}
```

I'd like TS to know that `res` has a property `books`

```js
const res: {
  books: string;
}
```

I tried many things but nothing seems to work.
Is it possible at all? Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a generic function like this:

```
const fn = <T extends string>(name: T): { [key in T]: string } => {
  return { [name]: "some txt" } as any;
};

const res = fn("books");
```

It seems like a bug in TypeScript that it doesn't allow such things, that's why you need the `as any`. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAeAKjApgDylsAEwhmgCcBLMAcwD4AKMAQwFssAuGdASk4G8YAbQDWWAJ4wqXALqdyVajAC+yWjD4AoGDDJYoAVzKIBg5m1kwARBBBsYUPJeUwmJJmDEBuDUu8bQkLC6JCgI9JYARiAgwhCW3J5AA) for an interactive example.

Comment: Nope, don't you see it in the TS playground? It's recognized as:
`const res: { T: string; }`

Comment: could you look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67107240/how-to-get-a-literal-type-from-a-class-property-after-passing-the-class-as-argu