# How to get a literal type from a class property (after passing the class as argument) for a computed property name?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, apollo-client, typescript-generics, class-transformer

a moment ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67105840/how-to-get-a-literal-type-from-a-function-argument-for-a-computed-property-name/67105923?noredirect=1#comment118616401_67105923) and now I have a follow up one :)

Please consider the following code:

```js
import { ClassConstructor } from "class-transformer";
import { useQuery as useApolloQuery } from "@apollo/client";

class Book {
  readonly many = "books" as const;
  bookData: any;
}

export const useQueryWrapper = <T>(cls: ClassConstructor<T>, queryString) => {
  return useApolloQuery<{ [cls.prototype.many]: T[] }>(queryString);
};

const { data } = useQueryWrapper(Book, "..."); // Book or any other class with a literal `many` prop
```

TS recognizes data as the following type:

```js
const data: {} | undefined
```

I'd like TS to know that data has a property books

```js
const data: {
    books: Book[];
} | undefined
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with a combination of [index access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD28DW0DeAoa0BOBTMAJvAHYgCe0AtmMRQLzQBEARokhI9JNMCRAC4BuTNFbIAImH5gAXF1rCAvunShIMAApgA5rjQi8hEuSo16TAA47cHLjF7EBwrGKSTpcs0pX8yFvQCyZgAqfnoMqDj4RKQU1LRyAtgAlsTa0IrC6L7+0ACKAK642GQASjYFIPwAPMHQuAAe-LjEBDBBtKH+AHzQESIA9APQBRCp6QDS0KnQwQDajPFkjAC60PzwPIbN8tDwzABWuMD80ADuyfwAFlzQSLgU8ABm0ABuYCBFswtLqwA09QAdNpAUxXBwAYwrLoIfV+MBASI5lMZvNFmZVis5PMVkosjk9ABhcBQQl8fjYAoneDYWq9BjEXBnaAACkB7LA2G0EE8tDmKwAlH1esEsk8CsQTskSCMILhCsUyAB1bBgCz+Wl1RrNVrtEJhboskSgHnQYnqMmOClUjaa7p-EQARyKJQAyhTxokPWl0AK5AqSuUIJUasFegAfEatXBPVK4Aj6LB4fgFbDENCKOzyMjeVTk0RsGAMUbyl3K1Xq4oshDISHswGMAUAfkB4ME0CGcDY-OgkYlBBjcYIeat0GhNj6stLipVao1LK0ujr7MbLfHEHbncXuB7fejscZBCAA)):

```
class Book {
  readonly many = "books" as const;
  bookData: any;
}

class Page {
  readonly many = "pages" as const;
  bookData: any;
}

type ManyType = { readonly many: string };

type QueryResult<T extends ManyType> = {
  // using K in T["many"] to create an object with a key of value T["many"], e.g. "books", "pages", etc.
  [K in T["many"]]: T[]; 
};

type ClassConstructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function useQueryWrapper<T extends ManyType>(
  cls: ClassConstructor<T>,
  queryString: string
): QueryResult<T> | undefined {
  return {} as any;
}

const books = useQueryWrapper(Book, "...")?.books; // Book[] | undefined
const pages = useQueryWrapper(Page, "...")?.pages; // Page[] | undefined
```

Comment: Looks promising. Give me a minute. I am double checking everything :)